# Как выводить по 4 байта в строке unsigned char

Tags: c++

Как выводить по 4 байта из строки `unsigned char`? Например, есть строка:

```
unsigned char[16] t = "valera123456789"
```

как мне из неё циклом вывести по четыре элемента? Я не могу воспользоваться `substr` так как это `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да выводить по одному символу, а каждые 4 - перевод строки:

```
unsigned char t[] = "valera123456789";
for(int i = 0; t[i]; ++i)
{
    putchar(t[i]);
    if (i%4 == 3) putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать старый добрый `printf` с указанием размера строки.

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    unsigned char t[] = "valera123456789";
    for(auto p = t; p < sizeof(t) + t; p += 4) {
        std::printf("%.4s\n", p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, объявление `unsigned char[16] t = "valera123456789"` некорректно.

Во-вторых, вот решение:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    unsigned char t[16] = "valera123456789";

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen((char*)t); i += 4)
    {
        char copy[5];
        strncpy(copy, (char *) t + i, 4);
        copy[4] = 0;
        printf("%s\n", copy);
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Это решение не адаптировано для различных размеров строк и выводимых подстрок. Надеюсь, разберётесь, в каких местах нужно заменить числовые константы на переменные, чтобы добавить универсальности. Ключевые моменты:

1. Чтобы скопировать определённое кол-во символов из одной строки в другую, необходимо использовать `strncpy(указатель на строку-приёмник, указатель на строку источник, кол-во символов)`. При этом следует обратить внимание, что указатель может указывать не только на начало строки, но и на любой символ, начиная с которого необходимо производить копирование. В моём примере, чтобы скопировать символы, начиная, например, с 4-ого, я просто сдвигал указатель обычным сложением (`t + i`).
2. Также очень важно в конце копии поставить нуль-символ (`0` или `'\0'`): `copy[4] = 0;`, т.к. в противном случае строка-копия будет некорректно распознана функцией вывода (появятся лишние символы в конце).

Answer (score 1):

Вместо substr можно использовать memcpy:

```
unsigned char copy[5];
memcpy( copy, &t[10], 4 );
copy[4] = '\0';
```